# График функции на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Необходимо с помощью *JavaScript* построить график функции `y = х^2 + (е^2x)/(х-2)` где `e` - экспонента (в степени `2*x`), `x = -5` и с шагом в `0.1` (т.е. `-5 + 0.1`) до `10` (можно и до `1`). 
Прошу помощи, или хотя бы ссылку на ресурс где объясняется как это можно сделать. 
Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

вот вам `y = x^2` на интервале `[-2,2]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let y = x => x*x; // функция
let z = 40; // масштаб
let c = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = c.getContext('2d');

// центровочка
ctx.translate(c.width/2, c.height/2)
   
// сетка
ctx.beginPath();
for (let x = -3; x <3; x++) {
  ctx.moveTo(x*z, -c.height/2);
  ctx.lineTo(x*z, c.height/2);
  ctx.moveTo(-c.width/2, x*z);
  ctx.lineTo(c.width/2, x*z);
}
ctx.stroke();

// график функции
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.beginPath();
for (var i = -2; i <= 2; i += 0.2) {
  ctx[i?'lineTo':'moveTo'](i*z, -y(i)*z);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas width=175 height=175></canvas>
```

Comment: подсматривая в Ваш код, решил сам нарисовать график этой функции. Но график у меня получился зеркально перевернутый. Обратил внимание, что Ваш график развернут, за счет минуса в этой строке `ctx[i?'lineTo':'moveTo'](i*z, -y(i)*z);` . Собственно, вопрос: зачем там минус? Для красоты итогового графика или это необходимость?

Comment: @Дмытрык в математике принято, что ось y смотрит вверх, так вот у канвы y - вниз, отсюда и минус

Comment: Понял - для необходимой красоты)

Comment: @Дмытрык просто чтобы верх юыл где принято

Answer (score 5):

Вот вариант при помощи `svg`, рисуем [суперформулу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_(%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

В [полярной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82) системе координат, суперформула выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения], где [image: <code>r</code>] радиус, [image: <code>а</code>] - угол

Вот такие фигуры получаются если подставлять в эту формулу различные коэффициенты, (смотрите сниппет для подробностей):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function superformula(phi, r, m1, m2, n1, a, b, n2, n3) {
    with (Math) {
        // считаем значение значение суперформулы для угла phi
        let d = pow( pow(abs(cos(m1*phi/4))/a, n2) + 
                     pow(abs(sin(m2*phi/4))/b, n3), -1/n1) * r; 
        // переводим в декартову систему координат       
        return `${(d*cos(phi))},${(d*sin(phi))}`; 
    }
}

// считаем n значений для углов в диапазоне [0, 2*PI] через равные промежутки
// и собираем все значение в команды пути для svg path
function pathD(n, params) {
    return `M${Array(n).fill(0).map((e, i) => superformula(i/n*Math.PI*2, ...params))}Z`;
}

document.querySelectorAll('path[superformula]').forEach(path => {
    path.setAttribute('d', pathD(200, path.getAttribute('superformula').split(',')))
})
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90vh;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 650 190">
    <path transform="translate(100,100)" superformula="30,5,5,2,1,1,7,7"/>
    <path transform="translate(200,100)" superformula="30,8,8,2,1,0.6,5,8"/>
    <path transform="translate(300,100)" superformula="30,4,4,2,1,2,5,2"/>
    <path transform="translate(400,100)" superformula="30,4,4,1,1,2,1,1"/>
    <path transform="translate(500,100)" superformula="30,12,12,0.3,1,1,0,10"/>
    <path transform="translate(600,100)" superformula="30,5,5,1000,1,1,600,600"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ты откуда это всё умеешь и знаешь ааа??

Comment: @MaximLensky я много занимаюсь графикой компьютерной, там полным полно математики и всего такого

Comment: @MaximLensky а еще я коллекционирую простые формулы, которые дают интересные графические результаты, вроде фракталов и вот этого экземпляра, которые потом можно применять для генерации текстур или чего-то подобного, конкретно суперформула прикольна для концентричеcких фигур и интерполяции между ними

Comment: а где ты эти цыферки берёшь ? в wiki же нету этих цыферок

Comment: это надо гуглить, я не помню где я это нашел https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/oOooVO

Comment: а как ты перевёл обычную формулу с геометрии в javascript ?

Comment: @MaximLensky эм, ну взял да перевел, это же 1 к 1 запись только на другом языке, glsl версия этой формулы еще лаконичнее

Comment: я если щас задам вопрос ты ответишь  подробно только доступно ?

Comment: @MaximLensky https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/ywJrMJ

Comment: @MaximLensky да, только не обещаю что быстро, скоро домой поеду, если по дороге будет настроение в телефон тыкать пальцем =)

Comment: webgl мне не совсем интересен мне интересно как переводить тригонометрические формулы в js

Comment: @MaximLensky возможно это для тебя https://github.com/Jam3/math-as-code

Comment: @MaximLensky переводить просто - заменяешь все математические операторы на их эквивалент из языка

Comment: @MaximLensky насчет формул - приведи пример что и как ты пытаешься или пытался перевести, а я подскажу

Comment: я утром (по нашему времени ) что то попробую замучу ..сам не знаю что и если не получится то задам вопрос ..скорее всего тебе вопрос задам так как не видел того кто ещё здесь работает с тригонометрией в js

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, математика прекрасна:)

Comment: @Arthur да, я даже подумывал задать вопрос в поисках похожих инструментов, однако пока не созрел

Comment: @MaximLensky не созрел ? :)